# Модель с количеством в Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-model

Решил в свободное время сделать API на DRF. В целях обучения.
APi будет схож с онлайн - меню.
При создании моделей, появился вопрос как правильно высчитывать общее кол-во одинаковых продуктов. Тоест один клиент допустим может купить 5 бургеров, и при добавлении их в корзину я хочу реализовать чтобы было наименование  продукта + кол-во + общая цена.
Если знаете подходящую литературу, тоже хороший вариант.
( не общую по БД, а по агрегирующим в django ORM )
Для большего понимания текущие модели выглядят так:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


User = get_user_model


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название категории', max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField('Описание категории')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название продукта', max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField('Описание продукта', blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='category'
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Basket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='allbasket'
    )
    products = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='alluser'
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} {self.products}'
```

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать `property метод` в моедли `Basket` для подсчета колличества товаров в корзине:

```
class Basket(models.Model):
...
    
    @property
    def get_quantity():
        return self.products.all().count()
```

Можете вызывать этот метод так:

```
basket = Basket.objects.all()

for item in basket:
    item.get_quantity()
```

Comment: Но это посчитает все объекты, а надо только с одинаковым id product те мне надо посчитать общую price для дубликатов. Я просто думаю не логично делать пять одинаковых POST запросов, хотелось бы организовать чтоб человек мог ввести количество.